# vue 3 transition-group appear not working

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-transitions, nuxtjs3

I have this setup in my code:

```
<transition-group tag="ul" role="list" name="flip" appear>
    <li :key="1"></li>
    <li :key="2"></li>
    <li :key="3"></li>
</transition-group>
```

The classes are not being applied, but they do exist. When I add them manually, it all works. So I am not sure why this is not working. Does `appear` just not work with `<transition-group>`?

Comment: 1. Please always supply all related code. CSS classes in this case. 2. My first guess is: put values into `li` elements.

Comment: @AdamOrłowski I said in the post "When I add them manually, it all works". The CSS code is working properly. The classes are just not being added. Also, there is stuff in the `<li>`'s, I just didn't include here.

Comment: I see, but try to understand. It is easier to help when I (we) can see all related code :) There might be little mistake or a typo somewhere. Try extending your question with more code, and the best what you can do to help me (us) help you is prepare reproduction on codepen.io or something similar 